# bot framework v 4.5 how to add extra meta data to choice prompt

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I would like to list few options to user to click and I would like to list by name but i would like to receive the id of clicked option.

For this case I thought i could use **ChoicePropmt** but for some reason it is not working in my case.

Code:

```
       const projects = [
            {
                value: 'project1',
                data:'214'
            },
            {
                value: 'project2',
                data:'213'
            }
        ];
        return await stepContext.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, { prompt: 'Select Project', choices: projects});
```

In the next step in waterfall I try to collect the data and log as `console.log(stepContext.result);` shows only the value property and some others like synonym, index etc but not data.

I can't receive the data property on the next step in the waterfall, I tried also Adaptive cards but still could not make it work! Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what your attempt at using Adaptive Cards looked like?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: For now I am including the id of project within the string in value property like for ex:  Project name (12345)  and than extracting the id using regex. Using Adaptive Cards was not working and it seemed un nececarry complicated for this case!

Comment: What channel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and have a look at the documentation. You can see that the [`choices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/promptoptions#choices) property takes an array of strings or [`Choice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/choice) objects. You can't just provide whatever kind of object you want and expect the SDK to know what to do with it, and `Choice` has no `data` property.

What you want is for the choice prompt to display a card with actions that contain hidden metadata. By default, it will construct a card with `imBack` actions which cannot contain hidden metadata. You could make the entire activity with the card yourself and then use that as the [`prompt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/promptoptions#prompt) property instead of just a string (you would want to use `ListStyle.none` in that case). But you might also want to try using the [`action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/choice#action) property of your choices so that you can use `postBack` or `messageBack` instead of `imBack`.

Note that not all channels support putting hidden metadata in actions. If you're using a channel that doesn't then there will be no way for you to do this.

Comment: thank you for ur answer, the bot needs to work same way in every channel,  so metadata hiding does not look safe!

Comment: What channels are you using? Isn't your entire question about "metadata hiding"? If you're not trying to put "data" values in the actions, can you edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to do?